# Arraylist length, I dont think my teacher is correct about this

Tags: java

We were told to find the value of `a[1]` after executing the following program:

```
int [] a = {0,1,2,3,4} ;
for(p=0 ; p< a.length ; p++){
    a[p] = a[ (p + 3) % a.length] ;
}
```

So my teacher work it out like this

```
a[0] = a[(0+3) % 4]; = 3
a[1] = a[(1+3) % 4]; = 0
```

So `a[1] = a[0]` therefore `a[1] = 3`

But I think the `a.length` should be 5 so `a[1] = a[(1+3) % 5]; = 4`

What is the correct answer?

Comment: Why don't you just copy/paste the code and compile and run it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are partially right.

Length will be 5.

But if you work your way up, you would see that

```
a[0] = a[(0+3) % 5] ===> a[3] = 3;
a[1] = a[(1+3) % 5] ===> a[4] = 4;
a[2] = a[(2+3) % 5] ===> a[0] = 3; // note that now a[2] will take updated value of a[0];
```

& so on

Comment: So the answer for a[1] will be 4 rite?

Comment: Yes , a[1] =a[4] that contains 4

Comment: Why a[0] = a(0+3) % 5 = 4 shouldnt it be 3?

Comment: sorry, a typo from my end

Answer (score 1):

You are right:
`a.length` is the number of elements in the array. There are 5 elements: `0`,`1`,`2`,`3`,`4`.

Therefore `A[1] = a[(1+3) % 5]; = 4`

Further expanding on `.length`:
When you access `a[a.length]` you are out of bounds. This is why you have `p < a.length` in your for-contidion. The indices are `0-indexed` meaning the 1st element has index 0. But non-the-less; if there is only `a[0]` present, there is `1` element.